# Programmatically Added Buttons not showing Text

Tags: android, android-studio, settext

I have an app in which I'm adding buttons to my layout programmatically to insure the spacing works out properly. In that method I'm using the setText method to change their text. however, that text isn't displaying. [Here's what's being created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2pX2.jpg)

Here's the code I'm using:

```
public void addButtons() {
    Button update = new Button(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams updateParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(size.x / 5, 200);
    updateParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    update.setLayoutParams(updateParams);
    update.setPadding(padding, 0, 0, 0);
    update.setText("Update Me!");
    update.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    update.setOnClickListener(new ClickHandler("install_install", this));
    updateId = update.generateViewId();
    update.setId(updateId);
    layout.addView(update);

    Button install = new Button(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams installParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(size.x / 5, 200);
    installParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, update.getId());
    installParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    install.setLayoutParams(installParams);
    install.setPadding(padding, 0, 0, 0);
    install.setText("Install LastBox");
    install.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    install.setOnClickListener(new ClickHandler("lastbox_install", this));
    installId = install.generateViewId();
    install.setId(installId);
    layout.addView(install);

    Button dlFamily = new Button(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams dlFamilyParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(size.x / 5, 200);
    dlFamilyParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, install.getId());
    dlFamilyParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, install.getId());
    dlFamily.setLayoutParams(dlFamilyParams);
    dlFamily.setPadding(padding, 0, 0, padding);
    dlFamily.setText("Download Family Build");
    dlFamily.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    dlFamily.setOnClickListener(new ClickHandler("family_build", this));
    dlFamilyId = dlFamily.generateViewId();
    dlFamily.setId(dlFamilyId);
    layout.addView(dlFamily);

    Button upFamily = new Button(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams upFamilyParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(size.x / 5, 200);
    upFamilyParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, install.getId());
    upFamilyParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, install.getId());
    upFamily.setLayoutParams(upFamilyParams);
    upFamily.setPadding(padding, padding, 0, 0);
    upFamily.setText("Update Family Build");
    upFamily.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    upFamily.setOnClickListener(new ClickHandler("family_update", this));
    upFamilyId = upFamily.generateViewId();
    upFamily.setId(upFamilyId);
    layout.addView(upFamily);

    Button dlAdult = new Button(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams dlAdultParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(size.x / 5, 200);
    dlAdultParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, dlFamily.getId());
    dlAdultParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, install.getId());
    dlAdult.setLayoutParams(dlAdultParams);
    dlAdult.setPadding(padding, 0, 0, padding);
    dlAdult.setText("Download Adult Build");
    dlAdult.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    dlAdult.setOnClickListener(new ClickHandler("adult_build", this));
    dlAdultId = dlAdult.generateViewId();
    dlAdult.setId(dlAdultId);
    layout.addView(dlAdult);

    Button upAdult = new Button(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams upAdultParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(size.x / 5, 200);
    upAdultParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, upFamily.getId());
    upAdultParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, install.getId());
    upAdult.setLayoutParams(upAdultParams);
    upAdult.setPadding(padding, padding, 0, 0);
    upAdult.setText("Update Adult Build");
    upAdult.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    upAdult.setOnClickListener(new ClickHandler("adult_update", this));
    upAdultId = upAdult.generateViewId();
    upAdult.setId(upAdultId);
    layout.addView(upAdult);
}
```

Comment: Please check the padding which you have applied. May be text is displayed outside button view because of padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that setting the text size on the button made the text show up. I guess it defaulted to be size 0?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine as far as you declare layout correctly here's a sample code base on your project

```
LinearLayout layout;
     layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLinear);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Now the `addButtons` method

```
public void addButtons() {
        Button update = new Button(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams updateParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 200);
        updateParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        update.setLayoutParams(updateParams);
        update.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        update.setText("Update Me!");
        update.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        update.setOnClickListener(new ClickHandler("install_install", this));
        updateId = update.generateViewId();
        update.setId(updateId);
        layout.addView(update);
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to show me here. This doesn't answer anything or explain a problem..

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: With the update this got more ambiguous. As far as I can tell you just copied my code and put it as an answer?

Comment: Base on your question and code snipped you showed us it's all good i test it just make sure you declare layout correctly.